# Is $P(A|B) + P(A|B^C) = 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to prove / disprove the following statement:

> Let A and B be two events. Is it then true that $P(A|B) + P(A|B^c) = 1$? Give
> proof or counterexample.

**Strategy:** I'll try to present a proof, and see what types of assumptions are made along the way in order to arrive for what is sought. Maybe then, after analyzing the assumptions made, I'll be able / not be able, to find a counterexample.

**Solution:**

Using the fact that $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ we can rewrite our expression $P(A|B) + P(A|B^c) = 1$ as a single fraction, namely:

$$\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B)}$$

Now, since $(A\cap B) \cap (A\cap B^c) = \emptyset$, which can very easily be verified by drawing a venn diagram and checking for three possible scenarios, namely when

- 1: $A \subseteq B$
- 2: $A \cap B = \emptyset$
- 3:$A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $A \nsubseteq B$

Sketching the three scenarios shows us that indeed this is true. Which means we can transform our addition in the numerator into the following:

$$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c) = P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B^c))$$

Applying the distributive law for sets we get:

$$P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B^c)) = P((B^c \cup B) \cap A)$$

If we choose $S$ as our sample space, then $B^c \cup B = S$, and since A is an event in our sample space, $S \cap A = A$ itself, meaning that we get:

$$ P(A) / P(B) = 1$$ which is not always true. Hence, disproved.

$\blacksquare$.

Please feel free to give any form of feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: @kimchilover thanks, should've been fixed.

Comment: As a simple counterexample, consider the uniform distribution over $\{1,2\}$, $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1\}$.  You have $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(A\mid B^c)=1$ and so $\Pr(A\mid B)+\Pr(A\mid B^c)=2\neq 1$

Comment: Your second equation is also incorrect, it should be true that $P(A|B^c)=(P(A)-P(A\cap B))/(1-P(B))$ from which you should be able to derive the correct condition (hint: it's related to the statistical independence of the events).

Comment: Meanwhile, what is $P(A|B) + P(A^c|B) \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: A variant that is true: $P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B^c)P(B^c)=P(A)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second equation is wrong. Notice that

$$P(A|B^c)=\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)},$$

and not

$$P(A|B^c)=\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B)}.$$

Therefore you can't add the probabilities to get

$$\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B)}.$$

Anyway, you can take the following example: Let $A$ be the event of getting 2 or 3 from the cube, and $B$ getting 1,2 or 3.

It is easy to calculate that $P(A|B)=\frac23$ and $P(A|B^c)=0$, and thus they don't sum up to 1.

Answer (score 4):

One simple counterexample:
Roll a fair die.
A=number is 2
B=number is even
P(A/B)=1/3
P(A/B’)=0

Answer (score 1):

Here is an aside comment. A very similar relation related to the proposed one is true:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A|B) + \textbf{P}(A^{c}|B) = 1
\end{align*}

That is because the conditional probability function is a probability measure as well.

In other terms, one has that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A|B) + \textbf{P}(A^{c}|B) & = \frac{\textbf{P}(A\cap B)}{\textbf{P}(B)} + \frac{\textbf{P}(A^{c}\cap B)}{\textbf{P}(B)}\\\\
& = \frac{\textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(A^{c}\cap B)}{\textbf{P}(B)}\\\\
& = \frac{\textbf{P}((A\cap B)\cup(A^{c}\cap B))}{\textbf{P}(B)}\\\\
& = \frac{\textbf{P}((A\cup A^{c})\cap B)}{\textbf{P}(B)}\\\\
& = \frac{\textbf{P}(\Omega\cap B)}{\textbf{P}(B)}\\\\
& = \frac{\textbf{P}(B)}{\textbf{P}(B)} = 1
\end{align*}

Hopefully this contributes!